# Passing parameter to user control inside repeater

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a repeater that lists data including an ID that I pass to a user control that is not visible until I click a linkbutton.  However, when I have clicked the linkbutton, the ID has been lost.

Anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong?

Here is the code for the repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="uxPolicyList" runat="server" onitemdatabound="uxPolicyList_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="smaller-ctrl">
                            <img src="Assets/Images/home-icon.gif" alt="Home Insurance Policy" /><%#Eval("PolicyNumber")%>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%#Eval("StartDate","{0:d}")%>
                        </td>
                        <td class="center-cell-ctrl">
                            <%#Eval("Renewal", "{0:d}")%>
                        </td>
                        <td class="center-cell-ctrl">
                            Postcode:<br />
                            <%#Eval("Postcode")%>
                        </td>
                        <td id='<%#Eval("PolicyNumber")%>' class="button-cell">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="uxPolicySummaryButton" CssClass="policy-link-ctrl" CommandName="PolicyNumber" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("PolicyNumber")%>' OnCommand="uxPolicySummaryButton_Command" runat="server">Policy summary<br /></asp:LinkButton>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <uc1:PolicySummary ID="uxPolicySummary" PolicyNumber='<%#Eval("PolicyNumber")%>' runat="server" Visible="false" />
        </ItemTemplate>
```

I have these get/set accessors in the user control code-behind, but they're always blank:

```
public string _policyNumber = string.Empty;

    public string PolicyNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return _policyNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            _policyNumber = value;
        }
    }
```

When testing, I hard coded a value in the user control.  i.e.

```
<uc1:PolicySummary ID="uxPolicySummary" PolicyNumber="545545-5454-54545" runat="server" Visible="false" />
```

...and it worked fine.  Any ideas appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to reassign value of `PolicyNumber` property inside `OnCommand` event with the value of `CommandArgument`

**Edit**

or save it into `HiddenField` inside your control

```
public string PolicyNumber
{
    get
    {
        return MyHiddenField.Value;
    }
    set
    {
        MyHiddenField.Value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi - I actually do that.  I tried to set it as a session variable, but due to the page life cycle, that seems to happen after the control has been loaded, so it doesn't load using the policyNumber and is therefore blank

Comment: try to save it into `HiddenField` inside your control check my edit

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be missing the ViewState backing store.

```
public string PolicyNumber     
{         
  get         {             return ViewState["policyNumber"] as string;         }         
  set         {             ViewState["policyNumber"] = value;         }    
}
```

Comment: That unfortunately had no effect - I'd have to set the viewstate value when I click the linkbutton in the repeater, but as said in my answer to Microprocessor below, that onClick, or onCommand event seems to happen after the control has been loaded as empty

Comment: I moved my code in to protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e) and it works perfect now! :D